# Firebase: Push to list embedded in an object with AngularFire2

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire2

I'm trying to figure out how to append values to a list in a Firebase object using AngularFire2. The use case is the creation of a simple scoreboard where the score is saved every time it changes by pushing the following `Score` object to a list:

```
{
    points: [15, 11],
    sets: [2, 1],
    timestamp: new Date()
}
```

A `Scoreboard` object in the database then looks as follows:

```
{
    event: 'Volleybal',
    home: 'Londen',
    away: 'Manchester',
    scores: [Score]
}
```

Where the `scores` array is an array of `Score` objects as described above. I need to be able to perform two tasks:

1. Query the `Scoreboard` list in the Firebase database to obtain the correct event (assuming the event is unique).
2. Update the `scores` array by pushing new `Score` objects every time the score changes.

Is this the right schema design and how can I perform these tasks using AngularFire2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the above schema would cover your use cases. I'd recommend that the `scores` property of the `Scoreboard` object is handled in your code (and stored) as an Object vs. an array.

Assuming the `event` property is unique to all the `Scoreboard` objects, you can retrieve this from Firebase with something like the below.

```
const event = 'Volleyball';

const scoreboards = af.database.list('scoreboards', {
  query: {
    orderByChild: 'event',
    equalTo: 'large' 
  }
});
```

However, if you have a unique key inside the object, it might be worth considering to use that key for the `Scoreboard` object itself, so the Scoreboards resource would look like the below

```
{
    'Volleyball': {
        home: 'London',
        away: 'Manchester',
        scores: {}
    },
    'Football': {
        home: 'London',
        away: 'Manchester',
        scores: {}
    },
    ...
}
```

Doing this would allow you to retrieve/update this object like below.

```
// Get Scoreboard
const event = 'Volleyball';
const scoreboard = af.database.object('scoreboards/' + event);

// Add a new score to the scores property of Scoreboard
af.database.list('/scoreboards/' + event + '/scores').push({
  points: [15, 11],
  sets: [2, 1],
  timestamp: new Date()
});
```

It's worth noting that Firebase doesn't actually store Arrays; if you present Firebase with an array it turns it into an object, with the keys being the indices of the array. https://firebase.googleblog.com/2014/04/best-practices-arrays-in-firebase.html

**Edited answer per comment below**
To display the latest stored value, you could get the value using something like the below.

```
const event = 'Volleyball';
const scoreboard = af.database.list('/scoreboards/' + event + '/scores', {
  query: {
    orderByChild: 'timestamp',
    limitToLast: 1
  }
});

scoreboard.subscribe(list => {
   list.forEach(score => {
       // Can access the values of the Score object here
       console.log(score.points);
   });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, this works. How can I display the latest (in time) stored value in my angular template?

Comment: Have updated my answer per your comment, once you've got the values you can use them normally in your Angular2 template.